# Mac repeatedly getting stuck at progress bar

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have lately been experiencing this problem on my Mac book pro 13" mid 2010 where it usually hangs and doesn't  resume normal working. I try to restart the computer but it gets stuck at the progress bar. I have tried everything from safe mode boot, PRAM reset, disk utility first aid in recovery and time machine restoration but the problem persists until I reinstall OSX (it worked the last time at least). Now it has hit again. Need suggestions on how to deal with it. I'm using Mac OS X El Capitan and it gets stuck at approximately the 90% mark.

Comment: What Mac OS X version are you running? From the progress bar stopping, I'm assuming El Capitan.

Comment: Yes it is el Capitan that's the one Apple provides for OSX reinstall

Comment: I experienced a similar problem that appeared after I upgraded to El Cap that seemed to be fixed by logging into all the other accounts that existed on my Mac. In my case, the wife and kids had accounts that they hadn't used since the upgrade. IIRC, the problem was that `mds`, the process that indexes for Spotlight (and other things) got hung up somehow at startup. Once `mds` had a chance to index these other accounts, the stall at startup went away.

Comment: @IconDaemon I do not have any other accounts on my Mac. Is there a way to fix the MDS issue in my case

Comment: The issue came about because the other accounts _had not logged in_ after the El Cap update was installed. Since you have no additional user accounts on the Mac, this is not a solution. You could try forcibly recreating the Spotlight index on the boot drive in Terminal with this command: `sudo mdutil -E /`  .

Answer (score 1):

Could be due to kernel extensions you have installed, I had the same issue and posted a blog tutorial on troubleshooting and fixing something like that:

https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-mac-osx-stuckhanging-on-progress-bar-will-not-boot/

To troubleshoot, startup your Mac in Verbose mode (after you hear the chime):

1. Hold down one of these key combinations on your keyboard immediately after pressing the power button to turn on your Mac, or immediately after your Mac begins to restart:

   - Command (`⌘`)-V
2. Continue holding the keys until you see white text on the screen.

[Start up your Mac in single-user mode or verbose mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573)

[Mac OSX Recovery](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201314)

[Mac Startup Key Combinations](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255)

Starting in Verbose mode should give you enough output information to debug the problem even further.  See my blog post for more in depth information and how I resolved my specific issue.

Cached versions of blog post:

Google:
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-mac-osx-stuckhanging-on-progress-bar-will-not-boot/

Archive.org (WayBackMachine):
http://web.archive.org/web/20161218201511/https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-mac-osx-stuckhanging-on-progress-bar-will-not-boot/

Comment: We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question, even though you wrote the post.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.

Comment: @fsb completely understandable ... I updated with basic debug information, and I own my own hosting company, run my site on CloudFlare, and all my blog posts are setup to be cached by Google, and Archive.org (waybackmachine)